# How do I enter cheat codes for LEGO Star Wars III on Nintendo DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds, cheats, lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars

[I can find lists of Nintendo DS specific cheat codes](http://uk.cheats.gamespy.com/nintendo-ds-cheats/lego-star-wars-iii-the-clone-wars/) for [LEGO Star Wars III: The Clone Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars_III:_The_Clone_Wars) via a Google search, however—how should one enter the codes in the game?

[image: LEGO Star Wars III: The Clone Wars]

The usual places,

- The bar where you can buy cheats, characters and hints;
- The in-game option menu where you can activate cheats;
- The initial menu

**do not** have an "Enter Cheat Code" screen like the Wii version, for example.

Does anyone know how to enter the codes? Do I need a red brick?

Answer (score 2):

You can enter the cheats in LEGO Star Wars 3 - Clone Wars at the "pause" menu at "extras". I only got a german [source](http://www.nintendofront.de/tipps-2999-2996-LEGO_Star_Wars_III__The_Clone_Wars_Nintendo_DS.html).

Comment: Really? I don't see how. I have "New game", "Load game" and "Options".

Comment: Just type the Buttons for the Code while your in the menu. Usually you will hear a sound if the code entry succeeded.

Comment: What codes are you referring to? I mean codes like [these](http://www.gamesxtreme.com/ds/game/lego-star-wars-iii-the-clone-wars/cheats.html). Thanks

Comment: sry my mistake ^^ see edit of answer for additional tip ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Should be similar in the DS version:

- Press start,
- Go to "Extras"
- "Enter Secret Code" and your code.

Comment: Can you please summarize the information in your video, please?

Comment: Press start, go to "Extras", then "Enter Secret Code" and your code.